# Botão compartilhar do facebook, como personalizar?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

estou querendo fazer um botão de compartilhar para colocar em um site. O botão basicamente irá compartilhar uma url com dados que já tenho guardados em minhas variáveis.

Ao ler a documentação do button share do facebook, vi que os parâmetros agora são pegos na declaração das metatags OpenGraph, o que é um problema, pois minhas metatags na página em que o botão estará já estão definidas.

Não uma outra forma de personalizar o botão passando os parâmetros de outra forma menos generalista?

Vi que antigamente esses parâmetros eram facilmente passados da seguinte forma:

`FB.ui(
    {
      link:'seulink.com.br',
      title:'titulo do seu comaprtilhamento',
      description: descricao do seu comaprtilhamento',
      image: 'https://www.yourrepository.com.br/imagem.png'
    },
        function(response) {
        }
    );`